# Machine Learning: Converting bash script into Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I have followed an online image classification tutorial using Tensorflow to create a variation which classifies an image by jewellery type. It's all up and running. At the minute I have to run this script in the terminal to test the model on a new image:

```
python -m scripts.label_image \
    --graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb  \
    --image=tf_files/jewellery_photos/new_images/1.jpg
```

It works.

Now I want to make an online front-end interface in which users can upload an image, the script will run and the interface will display what type of jewellery item it is.

1) How do I go about connecting this machine learning script to a front-end...

```
a) Do I store the script in my front-end repository and call it
   when an image has been uploaded by the user? 

b) I need to convert the bash script into python. Do I have to 
   convert the retrained_graph.pb file into something else to be 
   able to import it as a module into a python file?
```

Answer (score 3):

Put it on a flask server and make an interface for uploading files.
Logic and the graph files will reside on that server and whenever a file is uploaded, run that function to give the result.